# Azure Api Management: Any way to implement rate limiting in the consumption tier?

Tags: azure-api-management

I want to "rate limit" calls to my API. Let's say max 5 call each minute for each API key. My APIM is on a consumption SKU.

But when trying to add policies I get

```
Error in element 'quota-by-key' on line 16, column 10: Policy is not allowed in 'Consumption' sku
```

same goes with

```
Rate-limit-by-key Policy is not allowed in 'Consumption' sku
```

Is there any way to use rate limiting on the consumption tier?